# Coboundary of a simplicial edge.

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

The coboundary map is defined $\delta^{p} : C^p \to C^{p+1}$, and is the dual of the boundary map. This relation is described by $\delta(\varphi)(c) = \varphi(\partial c)$, where $\varphi \in C^p$ and $c \in C_{p+1}$.

However, supposed we have a $c'$ that's not a boundary, e.g. an edge of a triangle, how is the relation $\varphi(c') = \delta(\varphi)(\color{red}{?})$ defined now?

Comment: If a simplex is not contained in any larger simplex, then its coboundary is zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The simplex is the edge of a triangle, so it's just the part of a boundary, so it's not a boundary alone.

Comment: What makes you believe that, for any $c' \in C_p$, there is a $b\in C_{p+1}$ such that $\varphi(c') = \delta(\varphi)(b)$?

Comment: Interesting question. A single edge (like an edge of a triangle) is not a cycle, so it isn't in the homology group, so there is no need to define the dual.

Comment: I don't get it. Aren't you defining $\delta(\varphi)$ here? $\varphi$, and hence also $\varphi(c')$ is given.